# Is there a way to combine 2 match statements using OR or AND condition in Karate?

Tags: karate

Not sure if the below question is already asked and answered. Couldn't find any suitable references so posting it here.

I am testing a GET API call which accepts query parameters "search" and "fields". 'search' takes as input the value we want to search over 'fields' fields.

Say my json response is

````
{name: 'AK',
desc:'AK12',
status:'True'
},
{name: 'AK',
desc:'AK12',
status:'True'
}
]}```

I can pass search value as AK and fields as name and desc. It will return all the objects whose name or desc fields contain 'AK' in it
When I do a GET call with the above query params, is there any way I can do the below?

* match ($.objects[*].name contains 'AK') || ($.objects[*].desc contains 'AK')
````